# writing to Windows registry from intranet app

Tags: c#, web-applications, .net-3.5, registry

I have an intranet web application where encrypted connection string is stored in Windows registry (connection string is shared by some other apps). Application is hosted on a Windows 2012 server. In development/test environments (not production) I want to be able to modify this key so I can switch to different databases.

I do not seem to be able to write to it, I keep getting different errors depending on how I approach it:

```
string sKeyValue = "SOFTWARE\\SomeProject\\SomeApp";
RegistryKey rk;
rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sKeyValue, true); // Requested registry access is not allowed.
```

Tried:

```
RegistryPermission p = new RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.AllAccess, sKeyValue);
p.Assert();
```

also

```
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
rs = key.GetAccessControl();
string sUser = @"domain\userid";
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(sUser, RegistryRights.WriteKey, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
key.SetAccessControl(rs); //Exception: "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."
```

Comment: Why are you using the registry? Web.config is a much better fit for this sort of thing.

Comment: As I mentioned, the connection string is common among a few other applications on the same server, so rather than all applications trying to stay synced with each other on connection string, they decided it to encrypt it and put it in registry so all can use the same up-to-date connection string (one place to update)

Answer (score 0):

Allowing write access to the registry from a web app is just a bad idea all around. Automatically setting permissions via web code is dangerous and requires the code to have too-elevated privileges.

It's better to give all your web apps permission to read from the same web.config file, then get the shared setting something like what is described here.

[IIS web.config - same file for multiple websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364065/iis-web-config-same-file-for-multiple-websites)

Comment: Thank you. This is just for dev/test servers of an intranet app and I don't have the option you mentioned.  just need to know why I am getting these errors.

Comment: Can you manually add the key to the registry so you at least only have to worry about read permissions?